# How to use single sign on (Okta) in a Cordova app

Tags: cordova, single-sign-on, phonegap, okta

I have a Web App wrapped in Cordova that I'd like to add SSO with Okta. Most of the tutorials out there assume my web app will be serve from an absolute location (e.g. `http://example.com` or `htto:localhost:8000` but the problem is that Cordova apps are served within a file directory, `file://`. Has anyone had this use case or is aware of best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Change redirectUri in constructor to http://localhost:8100

```
Constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private oauthService: OAuthService) {
  oauthService.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8100';
  ...
}
```

Refer to this article : https://dzone.com/articles/build-an-ionic-app-with-user-authentication-okta-d